# Air bubbles in water

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, density

Problem :

Gas.  Density. (Composition)

N2-    0.879    (0.78)

O2-.   1.32     (0.21)

Why air bubbles don't disintegrate in water into different components due to difference in apparent weight (= weight - bouncy) ?

What I think-(not sure)

- it's a homogeneous mixture of gases.
- pressure is more inside bubble than water(surface tension)
- very slow process

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you created a system consisting of the pure water, the set of pure nitrogen bubbles and the set of pure oxygen bubbles, the system would end in the equilibrium with bubbles of the same composition. Nitrogen would be dissolving in water and escaping to oxygen bubbles and vice versa.

Equilibrium of a gas dissolution follows the [Henry's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry%27s_law)

$$p =K_\mathrm{H} \cdot x$$

Where $p$ is the gas partial pressure, $K_\mathrm{H}$ is the Henry's constant and $x$ is the molar fraction of the dissolved gas in the liquid.

If $p \gt K_\mathrm{H} \cdot x$, than liquid is undersaturated and the gas is dissolving.

If $p \lt  K_\mathrm{H} \cdot x$, than liquid is oversaturated and the gas is escaping.

The consequence is, that in equlibrium, all bubbles have the same composiotion.

Comment: But I am more curious to know and  understand it from physics point of view where bodies with density greater than liquid would sink and those with less density would float (partially immerged).  Ofcource N2 and O2 molecules will be moving randomly and an equilibrium governed by Henry law will get established.   If a bubble of air is released from under water . I think according to Archemedies law it would mean that a bubble in water will separate into oxygen bubble (sink) and nitrogen bubble (float) . The nitrogen bubble will pop above water to release N2 gas

Comment: Do you observe any sinking bubble stream during water aeration?